# Perl - Search array of words to check for a partial match in any part of an email address

Tags: arrays, match, partial

Again, a whole day and I am stuck again.

I need to use an array of words or var that contains forbidden words that cannot appear in an email address.

Either:

```
$baddies = 'smtp mailer sysop';
```

or

```
@baddies = qw(smtp mailer sysop);
```

or

```
@baddies = qw/smtp mailer sysop/;
```

There are more bad words in the array too, about two dozen.

I am not running the latest version of perl so ~~ and so on are not supported.

I have a loop going on that sends the bands schedule out.

In that loop I need to check to see if the email contains any of those words.
I realize there may be some good emails that contain a match but, that is fine.

I have tried literally dozens of examples after I gave up trying to figure it out.

Latest was:

```
####FYI## $uaddress is from the foreach $uaddress(@addresses){ loop.

my %params = map { $uaddress => 1 } @baddies;
if(exists($params{$uaddress})) {
print "yep, it's there"; #for testing
push(@failed,"$uaddress is restricted<br />");
```

But, everything I tried just does not do what I need.

I even tried =~ and so on.

I AM REALLY feeling stupid about now..

I need another lesson here folks.. Thanks in advance.

Update: I also tried:

```
$baddies = 'smtp mailer sysop';
 my @baddies = split / /, $baddies;
 # iterate through the array
  foreach (@baddies) {
   if($_ =~ $uaddress) #I also reversed that {
   print qq~$uaddress contains $_~;
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Through trial, error and dumb luck, I haphazardly got this below to work:

```
foreach $uaddress(@addressList) {
 $uaddress =~ s/\s//g;
    @baddies = qw(smtp mailer sysop);
    my @failed;
     foreach (@baddies) {
      if($uaddress =~ m/$_/i) {
       push(@failed,"$uaddress is restricted because it found \"$_\" in the address<br />");
      }
    }
##stuff happens with emails that passed like Email::Verify
}
```